# Unable to bind onChange event with select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind on-change event with my HTML select , but not successful in this,
This is my HTML code

```
<div class="size clearfix">
  <form>
    <label for="Size"><spring:theme code="product.variants.size"/></label>
    <select id="Size">
      <option>..</option>
      <option>..</option>
      <option>..</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is how, I am trying to bind onChange event

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    $("#Size").change(function () {
      var url = "";
      var selectedIndex = 0;
      $("#Size option:selected").each(function () {
        url = $(this).attr('value');
        selectedIndex = $(this).attr("index");
      });
      if (selectedIndex != 0) {
        window.location.href=url;
      }
    });
});
```

But somehow this is not working, not sure what I am doing wrong.Just to add all this code is in `$(document).ready(function ()`
By not working means, event is not getting fired at all

Comment: Put the binding code in document.ready and ensure you have add jQuery successfully

Comment: What means not working??? Is event fired? Are you binding event once element available in the DOM?

Comment: There is no `index` attribute, you should read the `selectedIndex` property of the `select` element.

Comment: perhaps a fiddle would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `index` attribute, you should read the `selectedIndex` property of the select element.

```
var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
```

Also since you don't have a multiple select element, the `each` call here is redundant.  `this.value` gives you the current select's value.

```
$("#Size").change(function () {
   if (this.selectedIndex > 0) {
      // Assuming your options have `value` attribute 
      window.location.href= this.value; 
   }
});
```

For the sake of completeness for getting the `index` of the selected option in the `each` callback you could use the `index` method:

```
$(this).index();
```

Since `attr('index')` returns an `undefined` value your condition is always falsy.